# How to get calculated data from one column in database

Tags: mysql, sql

im new in sql. I cannot get data with format what i want in one step. Now i'm using more sql commands. I want to get all data in one command because i cant to connect them in subquery with group by. Somebodys can help me?

example of Table i have:

| id | order_id | order_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | 2 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 1 |

Table i want to have after sql query:

| order_id | count | of | progress(%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 40 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 33 |

queries i use:

```
SELECT order_id, COUNT(status) as count
FROM `orders`
WHERE status = 1
GROUP by order_id;
```

```
SELECT order_id, COUNT(status) as of
FROM `orders`
GROUP by order_id;
```

```
SELECT order_id,
       CAST((SELECT COUNT(status) FROM `orders` WHERE status = 1) /
            (SELECT COUNT(status) FROM `orders`) *100 as int) AS progress FROM orders
group by order_id;
```

but last working properly only if i use where to single order id.

I want to make this data in one sql query to format i showed up.

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use multiple subqueries
here's a query that I used and worked on your example on the onecompiler.com website

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  order_id INTEGER,
  order_status INTEGER
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1,0 );
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1, 0);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1, 0);


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1,1 );


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2, 0);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2, 0);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2, 1);

select *
from EMPLOYEE;

SELECT order_id, count, off , count/off
from(
    select distinct order_id as order_id, 
    (select count(order_id) from EMPLOYEE C WHERE A.order_id=C.order_id  AND order_status =1)  as 'count',
    (select count(order_id) from EMPLOYEE B WHERE A.order_id=B.order_id )  as 'off'
    FROM EMPLOYEE A
    ) AA
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need subqueries to do this, SQL's ordinary aggregate functions already work as you want with your group by clause:

```
SELECT order_id,
       SUM(order_status) AS `count`,
       COUNT(*) AS `of`,
       SUM(order_status) / COUNT(order_status) * 100 as `progress`
FROM orders
group by order_id;
```

See example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1799db/4/0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sum and count with group by.

> ```
> create table orders(
> id int,   
> order_id int, 
> order_status int);
>
> insert into orders values
> (1,1,0),
> (2,1,0),
> (3,1,0),
> (4,1,1),
> (5,1,1),
> (6,2,0),
> (7,2,0),
> (8,2,1);
> ```

> ```
> select
> order_id, 
> sum(order_status) count,
> count(order_id) "of",
> (100 * sum(order_status))
> / count(order_id) progress
> from orders
> group by order_id
> order by order_id;
> ```

> ```
> order_id | count | of | progress
> -------: | ----: | -: | -------:
>        1 |     2 |  5 |  40.0000
>        2 |     1 |  3 |  33.3333
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=85e02e0f58ad7cc62413eef8ed309575)*

Answer (score 0):

i was described my problem without some details, w i want to join with other table but i see only record with status

oders_details
|  id  | order_describe | order_date |
|:----:|:--------------:|:----------:|
|  1   | sample 1       | 2022-02-28 |
|  2   | sample 2       | 2022-02-28 |
|  3   | sample 3       | 2022-03-01 |
|  4   | sample 4       | 2022-03-02 |

orders_status
| id  | order_id        |order_status|
|:---:|:---------------:|:----------:|
| 1   |     1           |     0      |
| 2   |     1           |     0      |
| 3   |     1           |     0      |
| 4   |     1           |     1      |
| 5   |     1           |     1      |
| 6   |     2           |     0      |
| 7   |     2           |     0      |
| 8   |     2           |     1      |

table i want after query

orders_view
| id  |order_id|order_describe| order_date | count | of | progress |
|-----|--------|--------------|------------|-------|----|:--------:|
| 1   |   1    |   sample 1   |  2022-02-28|  2    |  5 |   40     |
| 2   |   2    |   sample 2   |  2022-02-28|  1    |  3 |   33     |
| 3   |   3    |   sample 3   |  2022-03-01| null  |null| null     |
| 4   |   4    |   sample 4   |  2022-03-02| null  |null| null     |

i want to get some hint what i have todo, to get finally table or view, not complete solution, to better understand sql lang

Comment: i was added right join with group by from added column and now i have i want. tkank a lot for help :)

Comment: Please edit your original question to add more details to the question.